# Script or utility to change permissions on sub folder of the same name in Windows

Tags: directory-permissions

I have a parent folder call Projects, under that I have over 400 folders with a separate folder name (eg. Project1, Project2, etc). Under each Project folder there is a standard folder called Management, that should have restricted access but they don't. I would like to change the permissions for this Management subfolder, within all the projects (same permissions). If anyone has an idea on how to do this it would really be appreciated, thanks.

Scott.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple Java application that does about what you're asking. If I misinterpreted anything, you can probably fix it but I'm assuming your main task was to figure out how to modify permissions of only specific files.

My solution was to loop through the current directory's fplders (that being the directory that houses all the project files) and then through each project folder to find each management folder. Then, I used the [icacls command](http://timbolton.net/2010/06/23/icacls-changing-permissions-on-files-and-folders/) to remove permission from a specific user.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File file = new File("directory path");
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        for(File pfolder : file.listFiles()) { // Loop through project folders
            if(pfolder.isDirectory()) {
                for(File mfolder : file.listFiles()) { // Find management folder
                    if(mfolder.getName().equals("Management")) {
                        try {
                            runtime.exec("icacls "+mfolder.getAbsolutePath()+" /deny USERNAME");
                        } catch (IOException ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Be sure to modify the initial directory value (make it an absolute path) and the username who's permissions you are removing. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks H31IX, how do I run this java app? I normally use batch files of vb scripts so not sure how to run what you've posted there.Also, I want to change the permissions on this 'Management folder' to something else, not just remove what's there, so change to domain.local\management and domain.local\admins only. There's no rush for an answer as I'm sure you have better things to do with your time, which is appreciated of course.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't say I'm an expert with Windows permissions; I'm a linux guy myself. I had provided the source code as a simple interpretation of the solution, but if you do need it in a compiled state I can do that, I would just need to know the command to execute.

Comment: Thanks again but I think I'm in over my head here, I was hoping for a script or batch file, I've never used java oricacls before so I'd just be wasting your time asking you what to do each step of the way. I appreciate your prompt reply and effortthough.